# Html 'required' attribute only works in preview browser

Tags: html, forms, required

I have a html page with the following user inputs

```
...
  <form action="website.php" id="mainform" method="POST">
...

<strong>Departure date</strong><span>*</span>:
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="departuredate" required/>

 <strong>Return date</strong><span>*</span>: 
 <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="returndate" required/>

...

 <input type="email"  name="email" required/>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </div>


 </form>

...
```

The required feature prompts the user to fill in the field if it is left blank. However, it only seems to be working in Dreamweaver's preview browser. When uploaded to my site, it has no effect at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: might be an idea to paste in your validation code. if you want help

Comment: i get it, html5 and css3. unfortunately for me i'm still stuck in a css2 html4 world and i need js and server side validation. i wouldn't rely upon html5 css3 alone, unless your target audience are below the age of 40 or some other old number ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#required), (today, 27/09/13) the required attribute is supported in

- IE 10+
- FF 4+
- Chrome 10+
- Opera 9+

(not in Safari, not in Android)

Maybe you should implement a fallback feature in Javascript, anyways, until this gets better cross-browser support.

EDIT (to reflect Mr Alien's comment): You should also always have a Server-Side validation feature, because Javascript can be disabled or edited quite easily.

Comment: Side Note : Always have a JS validation and Server Side Validation(A Must) so that you can be sure that the data posted is valid. Because your HTML5 validation will easily fail in old browser, also it can be tweaked using tools like firebug, same goes for JS, so make sure you use Server Side Validation

Comment: Great thankyou. I currently use Chrome 10 (29.0.1547.76) and the required feature  still does not work.

Comment: Me too, on FF 23.0.1.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't upload the file correctly. It works perfectly. Thanks again everyone.